# Pull Image with Docker on Windows 10 : "failed to register layer ....Denied Access"

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create docker containers in a Windows 10, but it always gives me the following

> "failed to register layer: rename C: ....."

I can not find any thread to explain it, I´ve executed PS as a Administrator

I put the trace of the pull:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker pull microsoft/aspnet
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from microsoft/aspnet

9c7f9c7d9bc2: Pull complete
d33fff6043a1: Pull complete
b7c3bbe47489: Extracting [==================================================>] 123.8 MB/123.8 MB
1028e286eae2: Download complete
28e6f26ee039: Download complete
a0db4e322336: Download complete
failed to register layer: rename C:\ProgramData\Docker\image\windowsfilter\layerdb\tmp\write-set-255580435 C:\ProgramDat
a\Docker\image\windowsfilter\layerdb\sha256\b01351fac2d37b162190ef8dde977bbf009d8e3fa2446dd71595b142b73d28a3: Denied Access
```

Someone knows what´s the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

OK I have been struggling with this little devil for a while now. I have windows containers working on my desktop, but on my new laptop it was giving me a hard time.
I have changed permissions on all the C:\ProgramData\Docker folder at the beginning, to no avail.
After a while I realized that there IS a difference between my desktop and the new laptop was the fact that the laptop came preinstalled with McAfee Antivirus. Now I'm not sure if it's a mcafee only issue, or in general antivirus, but when I disabled realtime scanning for a bit, I was able to download the new image without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Docker Desktop as Administrator worked for me. [Before and After Restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZOA9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old as dirt. I had this same issue and none of the suggestions worked. I was able to fix the problem by switching docker to use Windows containers. Right-click the docker app in the system tray and select "Switch to Windows containers".

[image: right_click_menu]

Answer (score -1):

I have installed Airflow with docker on windows. But while pulling image of Airflow I am facing same issue and I had resolved this issue by switch the container to Linux

Answer (score -1):

I had installed Airflow with docker on windows and I am also facing same issue while start the airflow using following command "docker-compose -f .\docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml up -d". But I had resolved this issue by switching container to Linux